# Application crashes with segmentation fault

Tags: c, rm

I know what this error means, but I can't see what I did wrong here. I implemented a function to delete files and directories, and I also want to implement the "-i" functionality for a "rm" command. Command used: rm -i filename.

I get asked if I want to remove it, I type "y", the file I want to remove gets deteleted, but the program crashes afterwards and I don't know why.

```
int has_args(char * argv[], char arg[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while(argv[i] != NULL) {

        if(strcmp(argv[i], arg) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void print_error(char *this, char *filename)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Could not delete file: %s;\n%s\n", this, filename, strerror(errno));
}

int cmd_rm(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    errno = 0;

    if(argc > 1) {
        if(has_args(argv, "-r")) {
            remove_directory(argv[2]);
        }
        else if(has_args(argv, "-i")) {

            char ans[2];

            fprintf(stdout, "Delete file: '%s'?\n", argv[2]);
            scanf("%s", ans);
            trim(ans);

            if((ans[0] == 'Y') || (ans[0] == 'y')) {

                if(remove(argv[2])) {
                    print_error(argv[0], argv[2]);
                }    
            }
        }
        else {
            if(remove(argv[1])) {
                print_error(argv[0], argv[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        puts("ERROR: ");
        print_usage(argv[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `has_args()`? And why do you assume that the second argument is `-i` and not the first?

Comment: Because -i will always be the second argument. The first one will be "rm", the second one will be "-i" and the third one will be the file I want to remove.

Comment: But you cannot guarantee that and if it will always be there is no point in checking. What you do doesn't make sense. Just iterate through the `argv` array and check which option it is.

Comment: Well, I check what that is: It can be "-r", or "-i" or nothing. But this is working the way it is. I'll modify that later, but my quesion was, why does it crash after it successfully deleted my file ?

Comment: If it crashes it's not working correctly, it might be precisely because of this. You didn't post the `has_args()` function you didn't post `print_error()` any of those function might be responsible.

Comment: I've added those functions. But it works perfectly with the command `rm -r directoryname`, which follows the same principle.

Comment: Don't check against `argv[0]` because it will be the name of the executable. You check if the argument is there and you don't care where! Why don't you return the index where the argument is?

Comment: You should use a loop to walk through the command line arguments `int i; for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)

Comment: Just fixed @iharob before you said

Comment: @user3121023 What `trim()` function?

Comment: As a side note: `cmd_rm()` will always return `0`, no matter what happens.

Comment: @user3121023 Didn't see that! :)

Comment: 'char ans[2];' - just not again:((  Unless there is some huge, overriding reason, (eg., a RAM-restricted embedded system), get into the habit of typing [256] as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `scanf("%c",&ch);` as the answer if user can input only `y` or `n`, however if you like to support `yes` or `no` you may write the following code :

```
scanf("%1,3s",ans); /* Points out that the minimum length is 1 and the maximum length is 3 */
```

and as others have pointed out in some case `cmd_rm()` function should return `1` or any other value to indicate success in the deletion of file. However I can't see any success case in your function `cmd_rm()` and it would be better if you enclose your `trim` function.

But generally `Segmentation faults` are because of pointers not pointing to a correct position ( tricky pointers ). Debuggers come handy in finding these pointers.

Comment: Well, that didn't work out. I changed `char ans[256];` and I tried to scan like you did, but when compiling I get a warning: "format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[256]' " and it still crashes

Comment: You can debug and put all function defintions here so we can help you.

Comment: I guess there is no problem of `Segmentation Fault` in this piece of your code so post all of your code

Comment: bro when you want to get `y` or `n` as answer you need to define ans as `char ans;`. Then pass to `scanf` as `scanf("%c",&ans);`